# Extracting title and description from a youtube video url link

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I want to extract the title and a description of a youtube video link using jquery

the url would be like 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF5i6QXgR8c&feature=g-vrec&context=G24e6571RVAAAAAAAAAQ

how do i do this ?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760231

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the title of a youtube video if I have the Video Id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760231/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-a-youtube-video-if-i-have-the-video-id)

Comment: actually i want to do this using jquery

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF5i6QXgR8c&feature=g-vrec&context=G24e6571RVAAAAAAAAAQ&alt=json",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
    var title = data.entry.title.$t;
    var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF5i6QXgR8c&feature=g-vrec&context=G24e6571RVAAAAAAAAAQ&alt=json",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
    var title = data.entry.title.$t;
    var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
 alert('hihhhhhhhhhh');
  }
});
});                 this is what i am using but it showing some syntax error

Comment: syntax error                                                           http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF5i6QXgR8c&feature=g-vrec&context=G24e6571RVAAAAAAAAAQ&alt=json                                         <!DOCTYPE html>    this is the error