# Best way to get youtube title?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I found this code snippet to retrieve the title from a YouTube video and it works,

```
<?php
$video_id = 'y8Kyi0WNg40';
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $video_id);
parse_str($content, $ytarr);
echo $ytarr['title'];
?>
```

however many people say that this method is not safe for some reason and they should use cURL with YouTube's API, can you please explain why this method(`file_get_contents`) is not safe.

And if so I will appreciate a link to a tutorial or example on using cURL to achieve the same results as the code above.

Comment: dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760231/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-a-youtube-video-if-i-have-the-video-id

Comment: thanks for the link ambrosia's method works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$video_id);` to parse more easily since is XML format

If you want to use cURL try this [tutorial](http://snipd.net/php-get-all-information-from-a-youtube-video)